# Curl PUT "Method not allowed"

Tags: apache-http-server, http, curl

I'd like to simply store a file using curl with PUT metchod to my home apache web-serwer running on Windows 7.  When i issue a simple command like:

```
curl --upload-file /path/to/file/badname --url http://serverip
```

i get an error:

```
Method not allowed
```

Must i have any handler script on apache to simply add/store a file on a server using curl and PUT?